# (leaftlet) possible to use one ID map to display 3 tab?

Tags: leaflet

I have 3 tab first tab is PORT TO PORT which is default map you can see with 9 maker. The function is Norway to Vietnam (example) click on Button show routes, will display the route 1 & route 2 (which is all hard code).

Click on the second tab POINT TO PORT i want map show 4 maker only. The function key in FROM the Latitude & Longtitude To example Singapore, it will showing the route 1 & route 2 (similar with tab 1 function).

Lastly, click on the third tab VESSEL TO PORT i want map show 6 maker only. The function will (similar like tab 1).

I only want use one id #map for all the 3 tab.

Project link
http://fiddle.jshell.net/36twhxux/66/

Any solution or idea is welcome.

Thanks